# Get value from link using onClick function in same page

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

this is the javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function divHDVisible(){
        var div = document.getElementById('linkHD');
        div.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
</script>
```

and this is the jsp code

```
<font size="-2">
    <a href="#" onclick="divHDVisible()"><%=dataJobs.getID_Harware_Use()%></a>
</font>
<div class="row" id="linkHD" style="visibility: hidden;">Success</div>
```

what i want is get the value of `<%=dataJobs.getID_Harware_Use()%>` inside the div(div id=linkHD)
can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function divHDVisible(elem) {
  var div = document.getElementById('linkHD');
  div.style.visibility = 'visible';
  div.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<font size="-2"><a href="#" onclick="divHDVisible(this)"><%=dataJobs.getID_Harware_Use()%></a></font>

<div class="row" id="linkHD" style="visibility: hidden;">Success</div>
```